# How to create Audit Trail for Documents in Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

What is the right way to create Audit trail record for the changes taking place in documents in cloudant. The need is to create a separate document with any distinguishable document type (like Audit) that records the changes taking place in any document (updates, deletes etc).

Observed something called **Update Handlers** but that sounded more like a way to update the documents with certain internal fields (like timestamp) before pushing the document in the db.

Taking an **analogy from relational DB**, need a trigger which is tied to the UPDATE and DELETE operation of the table and creates a separate record in the AUDIT_TABLE, recording the columns changed in the current transaction.

Answer (score 4):

Although Cloudant keeps a revision history of each document, this shouldn't be used as a version control system as the bodies of old revisions are removed periodically during compaction.

One approach is to adopt a "write only" schema in your database. Let's say your document looks like this:

`{
  "_id": "<autogeneratedid>",
  "_rev: "<autogeneratedrev>",
  "ref": "abc123",
  "ts": 1464074759315,
  "status": "provisional",
  "name": "the name",
  "body": "## document body"
}`

Every time you want to create a new version of your document "abc123", simply insert a new one into the same database with new timestamp (ts).

`{
  "_id": "<autogeneratedid>",
  "_rev: "<autogeneratedrev>",
  "ref": "abc123",
  "ts": 1464074866595,
  "status": "live",
  "name": "the new name",
  "body": "## new document body"
}`

We can then create a [secondary index](https://docs.cloudant.com/creating_views.html) in Cloudant that allows us to retrieve the newest revision of your document:

`function(doc) {
  emit([doc.ref, doc.ts], null);
}`

This creates a view whose key is `[doc.ref, doc.ts]` so when we want to get the latest version of our document, we can query this view:

`GET <cloudant account>/mydb/_design/mydesigndoc/_view/myview?endkey=["abc123"]&startkey=["abc123z"]&descending=true&limit=1&include_docs=true`

to get the version with the newest timestamp.

Comment: This would complicate other nuts and bolts of the application, as am using cloudant query index at certain places, app is not based on secondary index purely.
Can i create another doc in update handler/validator, which will dump the existing values and then let the changed document be persisted, or something similar, to make this agnostic to any other dependency that my app has. Ideally, it should be treated as an aspect that i can apply/remove independently of how the app is behaving.